# Not able to set select on the same line with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set the select and the relative label on the same line, but without success, this is my code:

```
    <div class="form-inline col-xs-12 col-md-5 row">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="filter">test</label>
            <select class="form-control"></select>
            <label for="filter">foo</label>
            <select class="form-control">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[this is a jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28633/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-inline col-xs-12 col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="test">test</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="test">
        <option value="1">Some Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="foo">foo</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="foo">
        <option value="1">Some Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```